# Why is FindAncestor binding not working in GridViewColumn?

Tags: wpf, binding, gridviewcolumn, findancestor

I'm trying to create my own GridViewColumn and having some issus with binding.

Can someone explain to me why the following Header-binding does work

```
<GridViewColumn x:Class="interneProzesse_UebersetzungstoolNS.TranslateGridViewColumn"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:interneProzesse_UebersetzungstoolNS.Converter"
         xmlns:hk="clr-namespace:interneProzesse_UebersetzungstoolNS.Hilfsklassen"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:interneProzesse_UebersetzungstoolNS"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"Header="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Sprache, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
</GridViewColumn>
```

while it fails here?

```
<GridViewColumn x:Class="interneProzesse_UebersetzungstoolNS.TranslateGridViewColumn"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:interneProzesse_UebersetzungstoolNS.Converter"
         xmlns:hk="clr-namespace:interneProzesse_UebersetzungstoolNS.Hilfsklassen"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:interneProzesse_UebersetzungstoolNS"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<GridViewColumn.Header>
    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:TranslateGridViewColumn}}, Path=Sprache, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</GridViewColumn.Header>
<GridViewColumn>
```

`Sprache` is a Property of my TranslateGridViewColumn which inherits from GridViewColumn.

Comment: Do you get any `BindingExpression` error in your debug output window?

Comment: Why don't you use the first form if it is working?

Comment: @DHN Yes, it sais "Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='interneProzesse_UebersetzungstoolNS.TranslateGridViewColumn', AncestorLevel='1''." But I'd like to know why it cant find, because the `TranslateGridViewColumn` is definitivly an ancestor.

Comment: @nemesv because I need the second form for other bindings where I dont have an alternative.

Comment: Hmm, no idea...perhaps [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) can help you. - Btw, you're not really implementing your application in German, are you? O.o

Comment: @DNH :D Yes I am, but its an application just for internal use, so it should be ok. Usually i write my code in english. ;)

Comment: @DNH: It's a translation software, so it doesn't matter in which language you implement it.

Comment: @Marc yes, but it doesnt translate its code :D

Comment: But it COULD, that's the point... Just joking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few minutes after posting the question, I found my answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813237/how-to-use-relative-binding-mode-findancestor).
The answer basically sais the GridViewColumn wont be added to the visual tree, so bindings which uses this visual tree (e.g. FindAncestor) cant work.

So I subsribed to the Loaded-events of the elements which I bind to (e.g. GridViewColumnHeader) and did the binding in Code-behind:

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(sender as GridViewColumnHeader, GridViewColumnHeader.ContentProperty, new Binding("Sprache") { Source = this, UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });
```