# GridViewColumn Header Binding Fails When In A Style

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, binding, visual-studio-2012

I have a ListView where the View contains a GridView and a number of column definitions.
As Below:

```xml
<ListView Name="SampleListView" ItemsSource="{Binding SomeSource}" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding ColumnHeader1,Mode=OneWay}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource Column1Template}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding ColumnHeader2,Mode=OneWay}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource Column2Template}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding ColumnHeader3,Mode=OneWay}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource Column3Template}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding ColumnHeader4,Mode=OneWay}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource Column4Template}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding ColumnHeader5,Mode=OneWay}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource Column5Template}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

(This works perfectly)

I have a requirement to hide the first column on a user preference so I created a Style Trigger to accomplish this. The code with the style trigger is as below

```xml
<ListView Name="SampleListView" ItemsSource="{Binding SomeSource}" >
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="{x:Type ListView}" TargetType="ListView">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static p:User.Default},Path=ShowColumn1,Mode=OneWay}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="View">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <GridView x:Name="WithOutColumn1" AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                                        <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding ColumnHeader2,Mode=OneWay}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource Column2Template}" />
                                        <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding ColumnHeader3,Mode=OneWay}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource Column3Template}" />
                                        <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding ColumnHeader4,Mode=OneWay}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource Column4Template}" />
                                        <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding ColumnHeader5,Mode=OneWay}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource Column5Template}" />
                                    </GridView>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static p:User.Default},Path=ShowColumn1,Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="View">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <GridView x:Name="WithColumn1"  AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                                        <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding ColumnHeader1,Mode=OneWay}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource Column1Template}" />
                                        <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding ColumnHeader2,Mode=OneWay}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource Column2Template}" />
                                        <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding ColumnHeader3,Mode=OneWay}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource Column3Template}" />
                                        <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding ColumnHeader4,Mode=OneWay}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource Column4Template}" />
                                        <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding ColumnHeader5,Mode=OneWay}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource Column5Template}" />
                                </GridView>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
    </ListView>
```

**When this style is used the Binding for the GridViewColumn Header property does not work.**

But the Binding for the CellTemplate does and displays correctly.

The Output Window in VS Shows this Error

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=ColumnHeader1; DataItem=null; target element is 'GridViewColumn' (HashCode=56585823); target property is 'Header' (type 'Object

**Can anyone shed some light on why this occurs and how to resolve it?**

**Things Tried:**

- Using a RelativePath binding to ensure the DataContext is valid.
  (Suspect this doesn't work as i think the GridViewColumn definition
  exists outside the visual tree from this post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405228/why-is-findancestor-binding-not-working-in-gridviewcolumn))
- Creating a DataTemplate for the HeaderTemplate : Same result.
- Using an FrameWorkElement as a Proxy as per this post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660967/wpf-error-cannot-find-govering-frameworkelement-for-target-element)

Answer (score 4):

In Case anyone else is having an issue like this i have found a resolution.

The GridViewColumn Header property must be set and bound within XAML tags for that item as below.

```
<Setter Property="View">
<Setter.Value>
    <GridView x:Name="WithOutColumn1" AllowsColumnReorder="False">
        <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource Column2Template}">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content="{Binding ColumnHeader2}" />
        </GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource Column3Template}">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content="{Binding ColumnHeader3}" />
        </GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn  CellTemplate="{StaticResource Column4Template}">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content="{Binding ColumnHeader3}" />
        </GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn  CellTemplate="{StaticResource Column5Template}">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content="{Binding ColumnHeader3}" />
        </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
</Setter.Value>
```

Hope fully this will be helpful if you encounter a similar issue.

Comment: Thanks for posting. I had the exact same problem, and this fixed it for me.